# js getElemebyId() from a form input

Tags: javascript

How do I get the value from a form input? All solutions I found on web recommends using **getElemebyId().value** but it doen't work for my case. File *index.html* contains:

```
</body>
    <form id = "myForm" style="font-size:14" class="form1">
        <input id="myNumber" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="21">
    </form>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

File *myscript.js* contains:

```
var quantityFromUser = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
```

But this doesn't work, the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript) states at method 1 that one can use:

```
document.getElementById('textbox_id').value
```

but this doesn't work either, **.value** is not even a method for my case, only thing I get is **.nodeValue**.

Comment: It seems you are puttng the js script inside the head tag before the dom is ready

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: if `document.getElementById("myNumber").value` does not work, than you have an issue..... and .value is not a method.

Comment: As soon as you actually fill the input with a number, the `.value` property should be available.

Comment: I have edited with the structure of my files.

Comment: well are you reading the value when the user changes it? It is going to be what it is when the page loads....

Comment: if i console.log(quantityFromUser) there is no value, after user writes a number in box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're retrieving the value before the input has a value. You should retrieve the value on an event such as `input` or `change`.

For example: https://codepen.io/getreworked/pen/gQygzP